# OWASP ESAPI Performance issue for validation

Tags: java, performance, security, owasp, esapi

We have a web  application which uses ESAPI 2.1.0 jar to validate URL and query strings (eg. `http://www.example.com/?keyword=<script>alert("hacking")</script>`   request.
  We have implemented a new filter class Implementing the Base Filter  to achieve the same in the the doFilter method.

We are seeing a major performance issue for the same. Used Code below

Example 1:

```
StringBuffer requestUrl = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL();
String queryString = httpServletRequest.getQueryString();
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(queryString)) {
requestUrl.append('?').append(queryString);
}
String url = requestUrl.toString();
boolean isSafe = ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("URL", url, "URL", url.length(), true, false);
if (!isSafe) {
 logger.error("uNSAFE : URL contain scripting elements .sOMEONE TRYING TO   MANIPULATE THE url");

validation.properties:
Validator.URL=^(ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-      9)*)*(\\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.\\?\\,\\:\\'\\/\\\\\\+=&amp;%\\$#_]*)?$
```

Example 2: (Tried the below as well)
Created a simple program  with main function

```
         List<String> myList = myset(); (the list size is 700 which holds valid and malformed/invalid url)
         System.out.println("Total Size of URLS" +myList.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Item No"  +i);

    boolean isSafe = ESAPI.validator().isValidInput(
            "URL", validation(myList.get(i)), "URL",  url1.length(),false,false);

        }
```

Can you please help  to understand the performance impact we are having on using the above logic? (example 1 and example 2)
And also we observed the performance is drastically slow for UNSAFE URLS.

Comment: What's your definition of performance impact?  From the looks of it, you're basically doing unit tests, and in practice its not realistic to validate 700 URLs with *regular expressions* in the scope of a few seconds.

Comment: Also, why `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` in your code?  `StringBuffer` is synchronized and therefore not as performant as `StringBuilder`.  Also, performance questions like this are better suited to a test environment with a functioning application that is connected to a profiling tool like VisualVM or Jprofiler.  During a load test.  Not when you're running small demo programs.